# Need help deciphering protocol over RS232, SPI, or I2C to talk to controller with Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, protocols, i2c, spi

I have a motor controller which I want to receive live telemetry from on my Arduino. I have posted screenshots of the registers below and the way the controller uses these protocols. I just can't get any data using either three? If anyone knows how I can get the data using any of these three protocols your help would be much appreciated!! I am willing to try anything :) Any form of help would be much appreciated.

[image: Register] [image: RS232] [image: SPI][image: I2C]

**UPDATE**
Here is the code for i2c that I have already tried. I was trying to read from register 6. The code simply returns zeroes. Updated code to include Wire.available.

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int k = readRegister(0x08, 0x06);
  Serial.println(k, DEC);
  delay(500);
}

uint16_t readRegister(uint8_t i2cAddr, uint8_t regAddr) {

    // I2C write sequence to address the given read register
    Wire.beginTransmission(i2cAddr); // Module address
    Wire.write(regAddr);             // Register Address
    Wire.write(0);                   // Command Data = dummy zeroes
    Wire.write(0);
    Wire.write(-regAddr);            // Checksum
    Wire.endTransmission();          // Finish I2C write sequence

    // I2C read sequence to actually get the register value
    Wire.requestFrom(i2cAddr, 3);
    if (Wire.available() == 3) {
    uint16_t regVal = Wire.read();
    regVal <<= 8;
    regVal |= Wire.read();
    if ((Wire.read() + regVal >> 8 + regVal & 0xFF) == 0) {
        return regVal; // Checksum OK
    }
    }
    return 0xFFFF;     // Checksum error
}
```

**EDIT #2**
In my attempts to get this device to work I have tried using RS232 with the code below. The serial monitor shows nothing at all but they "Hello" message.

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial1.write(0x0); //write five zeroes to clear the command buffer
  Serial1.write(0x0);
  Serial1.write(0x0);
  Serial1.write(0x0);
  Serial1.write(0x0);
}

void loop() {
  sendData();
  delay(500);
  serialE1();
}

void sendData() {
  Serial1.write((byte)0x17); //device address
  Serial1.write((byte)0x6); //register address
  Serial1.write((byte)0x0); //zeroes
  Serial1.write((byte)0x0); //zeroes
  Serial1.write((byte)-0x1D); //checksum
}
uint16_t serialE1() {

  Serial.println("Hello"); //just letting myself know it got here.
  while (Serial.available()) {
    uint16_t regVal = Serial1.read();
    regVal <<= 8;
    regVal |= Serial1.read();
    if ((Serial1.read() + regVal >> 8 + regVal & 0xFF) == 0) {
        Serial.write(regVal); // Checksum OK
    }
    else {
      Serial.write(0xFFFF);     // Checksum error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is your code? Research is your responsibility. We only help you to see the errors that you made with an already made effort. Please provide your effort so we can see if there is a particular error. Also explain the issues that you have with your code.

Comment: Sorry, you're very right. I added in some code that I've tried using I2C. It just returns zeroes and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: You are calling Wire.read() without first checking Wire.available().  That's guaranteed to produce zeros.  Read the [tutorial code](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've updated my code in the example to include Wire.available. It also returns zeroes :\ so I'm not sure what's next. But at least it's one cause of error eliminated.

Comment: You are implementing the available incorrectly.. It should be: "if (wire.available() == 3)". Then in the if block you read all 3 bytes. The if way will make sure you receive what you asked for and that is 3 bytes.

Comment: Have you connected the device properly? Have you used I2C before? If not then the best way to get your I2C understanding up is to get a small EEPROM and access that via I2C. I2C EEPROMS like MIcrochip EEPROMS usually work as indicated in the datasheets. And there are many examples. As soon as you get that right uyou will have an idea of what might be wrong elsewehere.

Comment: I fixed the Wire.available to have the if statement. I have not used I2C before but I know my physical connections are fine because the I2C scanner sketch finds the device at the address 0x08. I'm not sure what's going wrong so I might contact the manufacturer. It's quite annoying not knowing at what point it is going wrong, whether the device receives the data or not. Is there any way of narrowing the error down?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will have to WAIT for the bytes to arrive. So, in your code, write

```
while (Wire.available() != 3);
uint16_t regVal = Wire.read();
regVal <<= 8;
regVal |= Wire.read();
if ((Wire.read() + regVal >> 8 + regVal & 0xFF) == 0) {
    return regVal; // Checksum OK
}
```

If this does not work, you can try to add also the i2caddr to the initial checksum (shifted by 1 position), since it states that the checksum is Byte0 + Byte1 + ... Byte 3.

One more thing: if you continue getting a checksum error, print directly the bytes and try to figure out what's happening

EDIT:

As for your serial code, there is a bug and some things to improve.

The bug is that you wait for data (call to available) on Serial instead of Serial1.

Then, again you should WAIT for three bytes to arrive, not execute the reading until there are bytes. So.. Try using this code:

```
uint8_t cmd[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial1.begin(9600);

    //write five zeroes to clear the command buffer
    sendWithChecksum(cmd);

    // Initialize the cmd array
    cmd[0] = 0x17;
    cmd[1] = 0x06;
}

void loop() {
    sendWithChecksum(cmd);
    Serial.println("Hello");
    receiveData();
    delay(500); // Wait for some time
}

void sendWithChecksum(uint8_t *array)
{
    uint8_t i;
    array[4] = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        array[4] -= array[i];
    Serial1.write(array,5);
}

void receiveData()
{
    // Wait for serial data to become available
    while(Serial1.available() < 3);
    uint16_t regVal = (((uint16_t)Serial1.read()) << 8) | Serial1.read();

    if ((Serial1.read() + regVal >> 8 + regVal & 0xFF) == 0)
    {// Checksum OK
        Serial.print("Received ");
        Serial.println(regVal,HEX);
    }
    else
    {// Checksum wrong
        Serial.println("Checksum wrong");
    }

    // Clear buffer
    while (Serial1.available()) Serial1.read();
}
```

Comment: I implemented this in my code but it still returns zeroes. I changed the checksum to -(regAddr + i2cAddr) but that didn't work either. Currently, all my values I receive are zeroes so the checksum will always work :\

Comment: @Peter stupid question but.. Did you put the pull-up resistors on the I2C buffer?

Comment: I have not got any resistors connected right now. Do I need some? I tried before with some 10K resistors from SDA and SCL to 5V but since I was able to get the address without them I didn't use them after that. Am I making a stupid mistake...

Comment: Well, I2C NEEDS pullup resistors, since the transceiver operate in open-drain configurations. If they are already mounted on the board (for instance arduino Mega already have them, the Uno doesn't) ok, but I suggest you to try and put them on (it's simple to do and then we are sure it works)

Comment: Ok, I'll stick them back on. I am using the Arduino Mega though.

Comment: Then use an oscilloscope and check the actual waveforms on SCL and SDA to see wheter the problem is the transmission, the receive or the channel

Comment: I don't have access to an oscilloscope :/ Are you sure it can't be a problem with the code?

Comment: No, I'm not really sure, but 85% ;) Your I2C code (together with my modification) should be correct. I'm almost sure that you should write `Wire.write((i2cAddr<<8)-regAddr);` to send the checksum, but anyway the device should reply 0xFFFF if the checksum was wrong. Try with that, though, then instead of calling `Wire.read()` use this function: `uint8_t WireReadEcho() { uint8_t result = Wire.read(); Serial.print("Received "); Serial.println(result,HEX); return result; } `. This should echo every byte you receive on the I2C interface

Comment: I tried this for one last time and it didn't work. I tried it both with and without Wire.available() in the code, without it it returned FF or 255, and with it the code returned nothing indicating no available bytes. I read somewhere deep in the internet about the i2c being unreliable so I have decided to try with RS232 as I can use the UART ports and software serial on the arduino to try another protocol - hopefully this one works.

Comment: Ok, try that and then report back if you managed to get it to work

Comment: I tried using RS232..but to no avail. I have tried switching over the RX and TX lines, but the code which I am just about to add in an edit to my post doesn't even return anything at all. The device flashes a green LED when I send a command so it must be getting the data. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: @Peter I added some code to get the serial working. Of course you are using a Mega, aren't you? If it does not work, try to swap RX and TX